# How to resolve Failed to start service controller: WARNING: no cloud provider provided

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, cloud

Background:

```
$ kubectl get services -n ingress-nginx  
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE   
ingress-nginx   LoadBalancer   10.108.245.210   <pending>     80:30742/TCP,443:31028/TCP   41m     

$ kubectl cluster-info dump | grep LoadBalancer  
 14:35:47.072444 1 core.go:76] Failed to start service controller: WARNING: no cloud provider provided, services of type LoadBalancer will fail
```

k8s cluster is up and running fine. -

```
$ ls /etc/kubernetes/manifests  
etcd.yaml  kube-apiserver.yaml  kube-controller-manager.yaml  kube-scheduler.yaml  

~$ kubectl get services --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE       NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default         kubernetes             ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                      21h
ingress-nginx   default-http-backend   ClusterIP      10.100.2.163    <none>        80/TCP                       21h
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx          LoadBalancer   10.108.221.18   <pending>     80:32010/TCP,443:31271/TCP   18h
kube-system     kube-dns               ClusterIP      10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP                21h
```

How do I link the cloud provider to kubernetes cluster in the existing setup?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect `grep -r cloud-provider= /etc/kubernetes/manifests` to either show you where the flag is being explicitly set to `--cloud-provider=` (that is, the empty value), or let you know that there is no such flag, in which case you'll need(?) to add them in three places:

- [`kube-apiserver.yaml`](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/v2.8.1/roles/kubernetes/master/templates/manifests/kube-apiserver.manifest.j2#L124)
- [`kube-cloud-provider.yaml`](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/v2.8.1/roles/kubernetes/master/templates/manifests/kube-controller-manager.manifest.j2#L50)
- in [`kubelet.service`](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/v2.8.1/roles/kubernetes/node/templates/kubelet.standard.env.j2#L142) or however you are currently running `kubelet`

I said "need(?)" because I thought that I read one upon a time that the kubernetes components were good enough at auto-detecting their cloud environment, and thus those flags were only required if you needed to improve or alter the default behavior. However, I just checked [the v1.13 page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/) and there doesn't seem to be any "optional" about it. They've even gone so far as to now make `--cloud-config=` seemingly mandatory, too

Comment: after going through many documents, still not sure about exact resources where I need to manually add the tag *--cloud-provider=aws* along with creating IAM roles and policies. I'm also fine with using cloud controller manager but there is no clear end-to-end guide for that, atleast I could not find it.

Comment: I would have expected whatever cluster provisioning tool you used to do that for you, just as `kubespray` will do based on the links I used, or (allegedly) `kubeadm` will do according to the kubernetes.io docs. That said, those `kube-apiserver.yaml` and `kube-cloud-provider.yaml` files in your `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` are just Pod descriptors, so you'll add the command-line flags alongside the rest of the flags. If you are not comfortable editing Pod descriptors, your life as a k8s cluster admin will not go well. I can't answer your kubelet one because you didn't post how you are running it

Comment: here is the [code](https://github.com/roytanmoy/ec2_k8s_nginx/blob/master/k8s/roles/kubeadm/tasks/main.yml)

Comment: may be I am using old version and that's why the flag is not there. Anyway, I will add it in each of kube-apiserver.yaml, kube-controller-manager.yaml. Is there any other thing such as dns name, IAM roles etc need to be taken care?

Comment: Do I correctly interpret that you rolled your own cluster installer? No wonder things aren't panning out. And yes for the [IAM roles and their instance-role friends](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/tree/v2.8.1/contrib/aws_iam) otherwise you'll be responsible for configuring the individual docker containers with AWS credentials and that would be a huge PITA